# Conditional routing always redirects upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have react router checking for a user, and if the `user.email` exists, it loads the page, otherwise it redirects to the `"/login"` page. This all works fine when using the navigation, but when I refresh the browser, it always redirects to `"/"`. How can I configure this so that it stays on the current route when refreshing the browser?

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const theUser = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (theUser && !theUser.includes("undefined")) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(theUser));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={user?.email ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={user?.email ? <Home user={user} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
        <Route 
          path="/feedback" 
          element={user?.email ? <Feedback user={user} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} 
        />
        <Route 
          path="/candidates" 
          element={user?.email ? <Candidates user={user} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} 
        />
        <Route 
          path="/view-feedback" 
          element={user?.email ? <ViewFeedback user={user} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} 
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `App` component mounts, the `user` state is initially `{}` and the component renders, ***then*** the `useEffect` hook runs and checks localStorage.

Use a lazy loader function to initialize the `user` state directly so the correct value is set for the initial render. Remove the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
  const user = localStorage.getItem("user");

  if (!user?.includes("undefined")) {
    return JSON.parse(user));
  }
  return {};
});
```